# Want to sort file according to UTC date yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.000Z

Tags: text-processing, sort

I want to sort dates according to 4th column I tried `sort -k4`. It's not working.
Example of the input file:

```
| 2021-02-17T15:38:53.000Z | | 83027fed-1570-4b39-ab4e-3f75f126cf1c | 2021-02-17T16:02:32.000Z | active |
| 2020-10-20T05:52:44.000Z | | 8cbd06fa-c24e-4e72-be1e-3340d0ea0bd5 | 2020-10-20T06:32:41.000Z | active |
| 2021-01-22T07:14:01.000Z | | c6df951e-3aea-4f34-9fc7-d6a077b7f369 | 2021-01-22T07:37:11.000Z | active | 
| 2020-10-20T05:46:28.000Z | | eb82a308-543b-4e1a-8f08-e17d2655e5c7 | 2020-10-20T06:26:00.000Z | active |
| 2021-02-10T05:31:48.000Z | | ed09b1d9-4a72-436f-9830-237798774cdf | 2021-02-10T05:55:28.000Z | active |
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the field separator and ensure that you count the fields right. In your case, the field separator is `|`. But this also implies an "empty" field at the beginning of each line, hence your "actual" field number is 5:

```
~$ sort -t'|' -k5 file 
| 2020-10-20T05:46:28.000Z | | eb82a308-543b-4e1a-8f08-e17d2655e5c7 | 2020-10-20T06:26:00.000Z | active |
| 2020-10-20T05:52:44.000Z | | 8cbd06fa-c24e-4e72-be1e-3340d0ea0bd5 | 2020-10-20T06:32:41.000Z | active |
| 2021-01-22T07:14:01.000Z | | c6df951e-3aea-4f34-9fc7-d6a077b7f369 | 2021-01-22T07:37:11.000Z | active | 
| 2021-02-10T05:31:48.000Z | | ed09b1d9-4a72-436f-9830-237798774cdf | 2021-02-10T05:55:28.000Z | active |
| 2021-02-17T15:38:53.000Z | | 83027fed-1570-4b39-ab4e-3f75f126cf1c | 2021-02-17T16:02:32.000Z | active |
```